# Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with [Firefox]

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click on the button named "Fast Path" and input 1067. But it is throwing up error like *Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with* 
Here's is the page source from Chrome if it helps.

```
<span class="textUpperCase" style="position:relative;" id="pfx$txtFastPath-containerNode" onmouseout="JKB.widget.manager.getWidget('pfx$txtFastPath').onMouseOut(event)" onmouseover="JKB.widget.manager.getWidget('pfx$txtFastPath').onMouseOver(event)"><label id="pfx$txtFastPath-labelNode" for="pfx$txtFastPath">Fast Path :</label><input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="txtFastPath" class="textUpperCase focus focus" style="position:absolute;left:90px;top:0px;;text-align:left;margin:0px" size="12" id="pfx$txtFastPath" onblur="JKB.widget.manager.onHtmlBlur('pfx$txtFastPath',event)" onchange="JKB.widget.manager.getWidget('pfx$txtFastPath').onChange(event)" onfocus="JKB.widget.manager.onHtmlFocus('pfx$txtFastPath',event)" onkeydown="JKB.widget.manager.getWidget('pfx$txtFastPath').onKeyDown(event)" onkeyup="JKB.widget.manager.getWidget('pfx$txtFastPath').onKeyUp(event)" onkeypress="JKB.widget.manager.getWidget('pfx$txtFastPath').onKeyPress(event)" tabindex="0"></span>
```

Edit: more readable version (*should* be semantically identical, but original retained to be safe):

```
<span class="textUpperCase" style="position:relative;" id="pfx$txtFastPath-containerNode"
      onmouseout="JKB.widget.manager.getWidget('pfx$txtFastPath').onMouseOut(event)"
      onmouseover="JKB.widget.manager.getWidget('pfx$txtFastPath').onMouseOver(event)">
 <label id="pfx$txtFastPath-labelNode" for="pfx$txtFastPath">Fast Path :</label>
 <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="txtFastPath"
        class="textUpperCase focus focus"
        style="position:absolute;left:90px;top:0px;;text-align:left;margin:0px"
        size="12" id="pfx$txtFastPath"
        onblur="JKB.widget.manager.onHtmlBlur('pfx$txtFastPath',event)"
        onchange="JKB.widget.manager.getWidget('pfx$txtFastPath').onChange(event)"
        onfocus="JKB.widget.manager.onHtmlFocus('pfx$txtFastPath',event)"
        onkeydown="JKB.widget.manager.getWidget('pfx$txtFastPath').onKeyDown(event)"
        onkeyup="JKB.widget.manager.getWidget('pfx$txtFastPath').onKeyUp(event)"
        onkeypress="JKB.widget.manager.getWidget('pfx$txtFastPath').onKeyPress(event)"
        tabindex="0">
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a button to click when I render the code provided, so I can only describe in a general sense what you likely need to do.

First, you likely need to tell your WebDriver to wait for a given time or until the element is visible.  This is called an explicit wait.  [See the docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits).  Here's some sample code:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,'name_of_id'))) # you can also use xpath or any of selenium's other find_by commands.  [See here][2] for a list.
```

Then you just need to `click()` the button.  It's as easy as the following.

```
element.click()
```

That's it.  If I've misunderstood your question, please feel free to clarify in the comments.  Good luck!

Comment: @nishanth glad to hear it!  thanks for the feedback.  :)

Comment: I asked another question relating to this topic. Will be glad if you can take a look at it. :)

Answer (score 0):

not sure about the python syntax, in java you can click on invisible element by falling back to a JavaScript driver, e.g. `js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);`, the gist of this solution should work well for you also, just write it in python